# How to keep the cell references from another sheet updated when adding new rows with PHPExcel

Tags: phpexcel, phpexcel-1.8.0

After using `insertNewRowBefore` method from the PHPExcel 1.8.0 library, the cell references defined in the active sheet (i.e. `sheet1`) are correctly updated. However the cell references from the other sheets (e.g. `sheet1!A10`) remain unchanged.

Is there a way to update them as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No there isn't.

The logic that updates the cell references in the same worksheet is heavily intensive and slow, and we implemented a trade-off rather than execute it for all worksheets, adding a very big overhead. It can be executed manually using an adaptation of the logic from the `PHPExcel_ReferenceHelper::insertNewBefore()` and related methods